# Share Mongoose schema between two servers

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, cron

I'm working on a MERN stack application for which I will use Digital Ocean droplets for each of these services - Frontend, Backend and cron jobs. I never had to work with cron jobs before and I got stuck with accessing my Mongoose schemas - which are in the backend project - from the cron jobs project. Considering that these projects will be on different droplets, how can I access my schema to perform read/write tasks?

Comment: After years of becoming wiser (or at least so I hope), I understand that I didn't need the schema to modify the database from another server. Because those were just cron jobs, I could've easily used pure MongoDB syntax to update the data, it wasn't mandatory to have the schema.

Live and learn.